# How to sum values and add row to array codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, codeigniter

mysql in model

```
public function dailymovedate($datee,$dateee)
{
  header("Content-Type: application/json");
    $this->db->select("dailymovement.id_order,dailymovement.item_code,currency.currency_name as totalamountbuy,dailymovement.totalamountsale,CONCAT(dailymovement.detials_daily,' qyt',ordersale.totalqyt) AS detials_daily ", false);


    $this->db->from('dailymovement');
    $this->db->join('ordersale', 'ordersale.idorder= dailymovement.id_order','left outer');
    $this->db->join('currency', 'currency.currency_number = ordersale.currency_number','left outer');

    $this->db->where('dailymovement.data_daily>=', $datee);
    $this->db->where('dailymovement.data_daily<=', $dateee);
    $this->db->where('dailymovement.totalamountsale!=' ,null,FALSE);
    $this->db->order_by("dailymovement.id_order", "desc");
    $query = $this->db->get();


    return json_encode($query->result(),JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

array json

```
    [{"id_order":"21","item_code":"SALE","totalamountbuy":"$","totalamountsale":"48790","detials_daily":" 153"},
{"id_order":"23","item_code":"SALE","totalamountbuy":"$","totalamountsale":"20790","detials_daily":" 5"}
{"id_order":"20","item_code":"SALE","totalamountbuy":"ERUO","totalamountsale":"22200","detials_daily":" 40"},
{"id_order":"19","item_code":"SALE","totalamountbuy":"TL","totalamountsale":"4500","detials_daily":" 45"}]
```

SUM VALUES AND ADD ROW FOR EXAMPLE
SUM VALUES totalamountsale IF totalamountbuy == $

I would like to add a extra field and make it like`

```
{"item_code":"TOTAL","totalamountbuy":"$","totalamountsale":"69580","detials_daily":" 158"}
```

NOW result

```
    [{"id_order":"21","item_code":"SALE","totalamountbuy":"$","totalamountsale":"48790","detials_daily":" 153"},
{"id_order":"23","item_code":"SALE","totalamountbuy":"$","totalamountsale":"20790","detials_daily":" 5"}
{"id_order":"20","item_code":"SALE","totalamountbuy":"ERUO","totalamountsale":"22200","detials_daily":" 40"},
{"id_order":"19","item_code":"SALE","totalamountbuy":"TL","totalamountsale":"4500","detials_daily":" 45"},
{"id_order":"0","item_code":"TOTAL","totalamountbuy":"$","totalamountsale":"69580","detials_daily":" 158"}]
```

Comment: Loop over your existing array, sum up the values, create an object/associative array of the same structure and fill it with the values, and append it to the end of your original array, before you return it JSON-encoded …

Comment: what's the condition on which you would like to check whether to add an additional row?

Comment: You do actually want to sum up the values of all records, right? (Because with your given example data, that should result in totalamountsale = 96280 and detials_daily = 243, but that doesn’t match your given example.)

Comment: the condition  totalamountbuy == $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// for demonstration purposes, using json_decode to get an array matching your sample data
$querydata = json_decode('[{"id_order":"21","item_code":"SALE","totalamountbuy":"$","totalamountsale":"48790","detials_daily":" 153"},
{"id_order":"23","item_code":"SALE","totalamountbuy":"$","totalamountsale":"20790","detials_daily":" 5"},
{"id_order":"20","item_code":"SALE","totalamountbuy":"ERUO","totalamountsale":"22200","detials_daily":" 40"},
{"id_order":"19","item_code":"SALE","totalamountbuy":"TL","totalamountsale":"4500","detials_daily":" 45"}]');

// initialize total array with 0 as starting value for the fields to sum up
$total = [ 'id_order' => '0', 'item_code' => 'TOTAL', 'totalamountbuy' => '$',
           'totalamountsale' => 0, 'detials_daily' => 0 ];

foreach($querydata as $row) {
  if($row->totalamountbuy == '$') { // if $, add up values
    $total['totalamountsale'] += $row->totalamountsale;
    $total['detials_daily'] += $row->detials_daily;
  }
}

// append total to existing array
$querydata[] = $total;

echo json_encode($querydata);
```

Comment: (Not sure if `$this->db->get()` returns an array directly; it might be a more complex object that just implement iterable capabilities. In that case, you’d have to go look for the method to get the result as an actual array or convert it to one first.)

Comment: thank you , but error ,  A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: models/Json.php

Line Number: 42
and   [{"id_order":"21","item_code":"sale","totalamountbuy":"$","totalamountsale":"48790","detials_daily":"153"},{"id_order":"20","item_code":"sale","totalamountbuy":"eruo","totalamountsale":"22200","detials_daily":"40"},{"id_order":"19","item_code":"فاتورة sale","totalamountbuy":" tl","totalamountsale":"4500","detials_daily":"45"},{"id_order":"0","item_code":"TOTAL","totalamountbuy":"$","totalamountsale":0,"detials_daily":0}]

Comment: Impossible to tell where that comes from, if you don’t show us your script and how you tried to implement this. My code only has about two dozen lines, so if you quote error messages mentioning lines 42 or 292, that totally lacks any context.

Comment: $querydataw = json_encode($query->result(),JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
 $querydata = json_decode($querydataw,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
 
$total = [ 'id_order' => '0', 'item_code' => 'TOTAL', 'totalamountbuy' => '$',
           'totalamountsale' => 0, 'detials_daily' => 0 ];

foreach($querydata as $row) {
  if($row->totalamountbuy == '$') { // if $, add up values
    $total['totalamountsale'] += $row->totalamountsale;
    $total['detials_daily'] += $row->detials_daily;
  }
}
// append total to existing array
$querydata[] = $total;
return json_encode($querydata,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

Comment: Maybe it needs to be `$row['...']` instead of `$row->...`, not sure if you are dealing with actual objects or associative arrays here, that could not be inferred from your example JSON.

Comment: models/Json.php Line Number: 42        if($row->totalamountbuy == '$')

Comment: As I said, try accessing $row as an array instead of an object.

Comment: yes sure, thank you for solved  needs to be $row['...']   foreach($querydata as $row) {
  if($row['totalamountbuy'] == "$") { // if $, add up values
    $total['totalamountsale'] += $row['totalamountsale'];
    $total['detials_daily'] += $row['detials_daily'];
  }
}

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me